# Initializer list constructor accepting iterators

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, initializer-list

The following [compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/aU9cQi) on MSVC:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator> 

int main()
{
    int parameters[4]{1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto b = std::begin(parameters); 
    auto e = std::end(parameters);
    std::initializer_list<int> il(b,e); // where is the constructor specified in the standard?
}
```

I used this behavior to answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47141731/1460794), but while doing some research I found that this constructor is [not actually in the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/initializer_list).

I turned off language extensions with the `/Za` and `/permissive-` flags, but it still compiles.

Is this a bug in MSVC?

Comment: Hmm. Why the downvote I wonder?

Comment: Neither gcc nor clang compile this, so it looks like a VS extension

Comment: @bolov Would you consider it a bug that the `/Za` flag is ignored?

Comment: I am leaning towards "yes"

Comment: @rex no. "The compiler switch /Za was an effort started decades ago to carve out a strictly portable behavior across several C++ compilers. **The effort was stalled** and we no longer recommend it for new projects". Read the full article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/

Comment: @bolov Thanks for the reference, I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Then is it a bug in `/permissive-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually documented in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/initializer-list-class):

> constexpr initializer_list() noexcept;
>
> initializer_list(const InputIterator First, const InputIterator Last);

but it seems to be a VS-specific feature